# Solving Klop's fixed-point operator problem

Tags: lambda-calculus

The following problem is attributed to Klop mentioned in Barendregt's book (as per notes I'm going through).

Here's the problem:

Show that $\underline{Y_2}$ is a fixed-point operator, where

$$
LET \ @ = \lambda abcdefghijklmnopqstuvwxyzr. r(thisisafixedpointcombinator)
$$

$$
LET \ \underline{Y_2} = @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
$$

Here's my try:

$\underline{Y_2} \ E
= \underbrace{@..@}_\text{26 @'s}E
= (\lambda a..qs..zr. r(\underbrace{...}_\text{26 letters not r}r))\underbrace{@..@}_\text{25 @'s}E
= (\lambda r. r(\underbrace{@..@}_\text{26 @'s}r))E
= E(\underbrace{@..@}_\text{26 @'s}E)
= E(\underline{Y_2}E)
$

$\square$

Are steps correct and reasonable? Thanks a bunch!